# ObservableCollection catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

From a backgroundthread i call

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => SortJobs());
```

This is what i simply do in the ViewModel of the Page:

```
jobsCollection.Clear();
```

After that, the collection is re-filled with objects from a database.

```
foreach(Job job in database.Table<Job>)
{
    jobsCollection.Add(new JobViewModel(job));
}
```

jobsCollection is an ObservableCollection and it is bound via DataBinding to a CollectionViewSource

```
<CollectionViewSource
x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
IsSourceGrouped="True"
Source="{Binding Path=Jobs}"
ItemsPath="Items" />
```

The displaying element is a custom variable `GridView`.

> A catastrophic failure exception (HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
>   occurs by calling Clear() sporadically and Add().

How can this be when i am in the UI-Thread?

I heard of some people having problems with a `ListBox` which looses its selected item. But a `GridView` doesn´t have a selected item.

Comment: Have you found a solution?